# how to append list through other python script?

Tags: python, list

how to append or create list through other python script?

ex:

1.py

```
list = [['1', '2'], ['3', '4']]
```

2.py

```
import 1
1.list.append('5', '6')
```

then list becomes

```
list = [['1', '2'], ['3', '4'], ['5', '6']]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you meant to 'physically' add the `'5' , '6'` to the file `1.py`, then you need to open `1.py` file in the other script and modify the text.

Assume this is your `1.py`

```
.
.
. other lines...

list1 = [1,2,3]

.
.
.
.other lines...
```

If I assume in your `1.py`, there is no other lines that is exactly the same as `list1 = [1,2,3]`, then you can do this:

```py
with open('1.py', 'rt') as f:
    oldlines = f.readlines()
    
for index,line in enumerate(oldlines):
    if line == "list1 = [1,2,3]":
        # find the line with the text you want to change 
        # You can simply change the text 
        # but what I did here is create the list called list1 
        # then append value to it 
        # then generate the new line and overwrite the orignal line.
        exec(line)
        list1.append(['5','6'])
        oldlines[index] = f'list1 = {list1}'
        break

with open('1.py', 'wt') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(oldlines))
```

Your IDE might complain `list1` is undefined, but that's OK because the `exec(line)` is creating `list1` for you.

If you meant to modify the list you imported from `1.py` while running `2.py`, then you need to change the name of `1.py` to something like `file1.py` that doesn't start with number. Because python won't allow module name start with number.

Also you need to change your code slightly:

```py
import file1
file1.list.append(['5', '6'])
```

Comment: yea i mean physically

Comment: i can`t find solution  to append list by modifying the text

Answer (score 0):

Do not call your variables `list`, `dict` or the like. That being said, you could use

```
from other_file import lst
lst.append(['5', '6'])
print(lst)
```

Which would yield

```
[['1', '2'], ['3', '4'], ['5', '6']]
```